# Read from /dev/input

Tags: c, linux

I have an USB RFID card reader which emulates keyboard. 
So when i put an card to it i see the string on a terminal window -i.e. `"0684a24bc1"`

But i would like to read it in my C program.
There is no problem when i use: `scanf("%s",buff);`

But when i use below code i got a lot (about 500 bytes) not recognized data.
Why? 
I would like to have non blocking read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  int fd;
  char buf[256];

  fd = open("/dev/input/event3", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1) {
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyAMA0 - ");
    return(-1);
  }

  // Turn off blocking for reads, use (fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY) if you want that
  fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);


  }

while(1){
  n = read(fd, (void*)buf, 255);
  if (n < 0) {
    perror("Read failed - ");
    return -1;
  } else if (n == 0) printf("No data on port\n");
  else {
    buf[n] = '\0';
    printf("%i bytes read : %s", n, buf);
  }
sleep(1);
printf("i'm still doing something");

}
  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting the `O_NONBLOCK` flag to make the descriptor non-blocking?

Comment: Also, when reading directly from the device, you read the _raw_ data before it's converted to characters you can read from like a terminal.

Comment: I just want to add that this is a lousy implementation of the RF-ID driver. it should be implemented as a character device.

Answer (score 18):

According to the [Linux input documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt), section 5, the /dev/input/eventX devices return data as following:

> You can use blocking and nonblocking reads, also select() on the
>   /dev/input/eventX devices, and you'll always get a whole number of
>   input events on a read. Their layout is:
>
> ```
> struct input_event {
>       struct timeval time;
>       unsigned short type;
>       unsigned short code;
>       unsigned int value; };
> ```
>
> 'time' is the timestamp, it returns the time at which the event
>   happened. Type is for example EV_REL for relative moment, EV_KEY for a
>   keypress or release. More types are defined in include/linux/input.h.
>
> 'code' is event code, for example REL_X or KEY_BACKSPACE, again a
>   complete list is in include/linux/input.h.
>
> 'value' is the value the event carries. Either a relative change for
>   EV_REL, absolute new value for EV_ABS (joysticks ...), or 0 for EV_KEY
>   for release, 1 for keypress and 2 for autorepeat.

Comment: input events are one per line? or no delimiter used, just divide by size ?

Comment: @Nanyo: It's binary data, there are no lines. When you read, you effectively get an array of `struct input_event` elements (possibly only 1).

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <poll.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int timeout_ms = 5000;
    char input_dev[] = "/dev/input/event17\0";
    int st;
    int ret;
    struct pollfd fds[1];

    fds[0].fd = open(input_dev, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);

    if(fds[0].fd<0)
    {
        printf("error unable open for reading '%s'\n",input_dev);
        return(0);
    }

    const int input_size = 4096;
    unsigned char input_data[input_size];
    memset(input_data,0,input_size);

    fds[0].events = POLLIN;

    int exit_on_key_press_count = 10;

    while(true)
    {
        ret = poll(fds, 1, timeout_ms);

        if(ret>0)
        {
            if(fds[0].revents)
            {
                ssize_t r = read(fds[0].fd,input_data,input_size);

                if(r<0)
                {
                    printf("error %d\n",(int)r);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("total bytes read %d/%d\n",(int)r,input_size);

                    for(int i = 0; i<r;i++)
                    {
                        printf("%02X ",(unsigned char)input_data[i]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    memset(input_data,0,input_size);

                    exit_on_key_press_count--;
                    if(exit_on_key_press_count<1)
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("error\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("timeout\n");
        }
    }

    close(fds[0].fd);
    return 0;
}
```

$ sudo ./keypressed

total bytes read 72/4096

35 49 C9 5C 00 00 00 00 38 27 0B 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 04 00 5A 00 07 00 35 49 C9 5C 00 00 00 00 38 27 0B 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 50 00 01 00 00 00 35 49 C9 5C 00 00 00 00 38 27 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

This is raw data, to convert to some key, I need to read 'Linux input documentation' link abave...

Answer (score -1):

Your code is clearly wrong at opening an event device under `/dev/input/`. Even your error message is contradicting the choice:

```
perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyAMA0 - ");
```

Reads from `/dev/input/eventN` files return binary data with event descriptions (like pointer moving or button presses), not text. Your probably want to open some sort of serial emulation device instead.

---

*10-year answer anniversary edit*

Consider [How to debug the input from an input-device (/dev/input/event*)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5218/3097) on Unix.SE.

There's an easy to use **reference decoder** for `/dev/input/eventN` content. You can use it to verify and compare your code against.

Comment: Judging by the title, he actually does want to read from something under `/dev/input`, not `/dev/ttyAMA0`. The error message is incorrect.