# How do determine key presses in C++

Tags: c++, linux, keyboard, emulation, keylistener

I am working on a CHIP-8 emulator to be used on a Linux system.  As I understand it, I need to get keyboard input from (any) 16 keys and map these to a hex keypad.  Once I get the inputs, I have no trouble mapping them to the 16 CHIP-8 keys.

However, I cannot figure out how to actually tell if a key is pressed.  I believe in Java I would use keylistener, but I cannot find anything analogous for Linux in C++.  Is there a way I can tell what (if any) specific keys are pressed at any given time?  Something like a getKeyState function I could call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a GUI or Command-line application? In commandline, you'd use `tcsetattr` and set a timeout which allows you to use a `read` style function to check if there is input - or use a library such as `ncurses` which has functions to "check if a key has been pressed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this tutorial on `ncurses`.  [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/keys.html).  I have confirmed that on my MacBook Pro, Mavericks 10.9.1, with the Xcode Command Line Tools installation, that the `ncurses.h` is a symbolic link to `curses.h`, both located in `/usr/include`.  This is the [NCURSES Introduction page](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html).

I have not created a specific class myself.  However, some searching on `/dev/input/eventX`, where X seems to be either a zero or one finds these two separate posts:[Read from /dev/input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949163/read-from-dev-input/15949311#15949311) and [linux keypress events](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/8206/).

Answer (score 0):

Your program may read the characters from standard input.

You can use `fgets()` library function to perform the reading.

See, for example:

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets
- [how to read string entered by user in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921)

Comment: That's not particularly useful if you actually want to also do other things, and pretend that keypresses are for example interrupts or polled events in some "hardware" in the chip emulator.

Answer (score 0):

In linuxOS, you can use: [`getchar`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) function in `stdio.h` header file.
Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char pressedKey;
    std::cout << "Press the key 'A' to continue: ";
    pressedKey = getchar();
    if(pressedKey == 'A') {
        std::cout << "Lets continue\n";
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Or on windowsOS, you can use `getch()` in `conio.h` header file
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Press any key to continue: ";
    int key = getch();
    std::cout << "You pressed: " << key << "\n";
    if(key == 'k' || key == 'K') {
        std::cout << "You pressed k, i love letter k.\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the recommended approach would be to use [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) as already mentioned by @CPlusPlus OOA and D.

Although you could implement a non-blocking "key-press-detector" with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>

#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int kbhit(void) {
    struct termios oldt, newt;
    int ch;
    int oldf;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    oldf = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf | O_NONBLOCK);

    ch = getchar();

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf);

    if(ch != EOF) {
        ungetc(ch, stdin);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

char get_char(){
    int k;
    int i = 0;
    while(i == 0){
        if(kbhit()){
            k = _getch();
            i++;
        }
    }
    return char(k);
}

int main() {
    while(1) {
        while(!kbhit()) {
            // Works continuously until interrupted by keyboard input.
            printf("Continuous...\n");
        }
        int c = get_char(); 
        std::cout << c;
        break; // Or whatever you want to do...
    }
    return 0;
}
```